# How can I view database data when running Firestore local emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've setup the Firebase [local emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) and have my iOS application hitting the local server. I'm wanting to verify whether some cloud functions (on document write) are executing as expected, but I can't validate whether the data is there or not. I can do this by running `deploy` and checking the Firebase console database tab, but that's only a viable solution during development. I suppose I could also do a `get` from the iOS client, but hoping there's an easier way to just view the JSON.

The CLI prints out a number of local URLs but none have any data I can see:

```
✔  hub: emulator hub started at http://localhost:4400
✔  functions: functions emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  firestore: firestore emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
✔  firestore: firestore emulator started at http://localhost:8080
i  firestore: For testing set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080
```

Comment: Other than performing your own queries against the emulator, there is currently no tool provided by Firebase to view the data.  Feel free to file a feature request for a tool to do so.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On May 21, 2020 the Firebase team has [introduced](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/05/local-firebase-emulator-ui.html) the Emulator UI. One of the features available is data management for Firestore and Realtime Database

Basically you have to make sure to have Firebase CLI at least version 8.4.0 installed

Once you have initialised your project with `firebase init`, you'll be able to access the Emulator UI in your web browser at `localhost:4000` after executing the following command

`firebase emulators:start`