# How do you see database entities in the App Engine Firestore emulator?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I got the Firestore emulator up and running using [this](https://github.com/smartninja/gae-2nd-gen-examples/tree/master/simple-app-firestore) example. With the old Datastore, the local website was hosted on localhost:8080 and the admin server (where you could see the database entries) was hosted on localhost:8000. How can I see the local database entries with the new Firestore emulator?

Comment: Already asked here (there is no tool yet): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61704839/how-can-i-view-database-data-when-running-firestore-local-emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already described comments [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61704839/how-can-i-view-database-data-when-running-firestore-local-emulator) at the moment currently no tool provided to view the data. Feel free to file a feature request for a tool to do so.

Follow Google Support [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to do it. I hope this will help.